# Make can't compile any AUR package

Tags: linux, antergos

I have installed antergos recently and found this error when trying to install any packages through pacaur or yaourt (including the package manager). Using Arch linux, antergos distro on na 64-bit os. Any hints on what it could be?

**pacaurt -S i3-gaps-next-git**

```
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl"
compilation error: file /tmp/xmlto-xsl.CjmcEu line 4 element import
xsl:import : unable to load http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3797: man/i3.1] Error 5
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pamac-build-cesard11/i3-gaps-next-git/src/i3/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1242: all] Error 2
```

An user recommended running the following command:
**XML_CATALOG_FILES="/usr/local/etc/xml/catalog" yaourt -S i3-gaps-next-git**
resulting in a different error:

```
xmlto: /tmp/yaourt-tmp-cesard11/aur-i3-gaps-next-git/src/i3/build/man/i3.xml does not validate (status 3)
xmlto: Fix document syntax or use --skip-validation option
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-cesard11/aur-i3-gaps-next-git/src/i3/build/man/i3.xml:2: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
D DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
                                                                               ^
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd
warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
validity error : Could not load the external subset "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
Document /tmp/yaourt-tmp-cesard11/aur-i3-gaps-next-git/src/i3/build/man/i3.xml does not validate
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3797: man/i3.1] Error 13
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-cesard11/aur-i3-gaps-next-git/src/i3/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1242: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet? The required resources appear to be available at the time of writing.

Comment: Have you installed the docbook packages (at least`docbook-xml` and `docbook-xsl`, maybe also `docbook2x` or `docbook-utils`) and as general rule, `base-devel`?

Comment: SourceForge is temporally offline, not all the site, but some links are temporally unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently also came across this.

Following the instructions on the arch wiki at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docbook#Compilation_errors

I ran `pacman -S docbook-xml docbook-xsl` which without `--needed` reinstalls the packages.

After this, I was able to build successfully.